# How do I find the most common instance for a customer?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I want to determine the most common store a customer shops at. For example, I have a table that lists the store someone shopped.

Customer_ID, Store_Number:

1456, 255

1456, 255

1456, 266

1456, 277

1456, 288

I want to write a query in SFMC where it returns one row for customer 1456 and store number 255 since is the most common store for that customer. The queries I have attempted failed in SFMC but work in other SQL databases in the past.

**This is the sql statement I used:**

```
SELECT
    PHD_COMPANY_CODE,
    PHD_LOYALTY_DNLD_REFID,
    PHD_SALES_DATE,
    PHD_TRNSACT_START_TM,
    PHD_TOT_SALE,
    PHD_PIN_NO,
    PHD_CUST_ZIP_CODE,
    SSO_CUSTOMER_ID,
    PHD_PCL_REG_NO,
    PHD_PCL_BATCH_NO,
    PHD_INVOICE_NO,
    PHD_HEADER_DATE,
    [Import Date],
    PHD_PCL_STR_NO,
    COUNT(PHD_PCL_STR_NO) as 'PHD_PCL_STR_NO_occurrence'
FROM [Store Frequency]
GROUP BY PHD_PCL_STR_NO
ORDER BY PHD_PCL_STR_NO_occurrence DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please add the SQL-statement you tried to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the SQL I used with the fields in my database:

SELECT PHD_COMPANY_CODE, PHD_LOYALTY_DNLD_REFID, PHD_SALES_DATE, PHD_TRNSACT_START_TM, PHD_TOT_SALE, PHD_PIN_NO, PHD_CUST_ZIP_CODE, SSO_CUSTOMER_ID, PHD_PCL_REG_NO, 
PHD_PCL_BATCH_NO, PHD_INVOICE_NO, PHD_HEADER_DATE, [Import Date], PHD_PCL_STR_NO, COUNT(PHD_PCL_STR_NO) as 'PHD_PCL_STR_NO_occurrence' FROM [Store Frequency] GROUP BY PHD_PCL_STR_NO
ORDER BY PHD_PCL_STR_NO_occurrence DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: This is the error I get: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
If I remove the LIMIT I get: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this.  The innermost query counts the stores by customer.  The next query out ranks them from highest to lowest.  The outermost query picks the top one per customer.

```
select
x.[customer id]
, x.store_number
from (
    select
    w.[customer id]
    , w.store_number
    , row_number() over (partition by w.customer_id order by w.counter desc) ranking
    from (
       select
       [customer id]
       , store_number
       , count(*) counter
       from [Store Frequency] 
       group by 
       [customer id]
       , store_number
    ) w
) x
where x.ranking = 1
```

Comment: That worked now I need to validate it to ensure it gave me the correct data. Thanks for the help! Still trying to figure out SFMC queries.

Comment: Good deal.  SFMC queries use Transact-SQL (T-SQL) syntax with some limitations -- can't do CTE and anything other than SELECT statements.